# Ramda: Filter Object With Dynamic Keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ramda.js

I have this object:

```
const data = 
{
  "avaiable_items": {"1": [201259, 201303],"2": [201303], "3": [201259]},
  "items": [{"id": "201259","name": "ABC"},{"id": "201303","name": "DEF"}]
}
```

I need to filter `"items"` based on `"avaiable_items"` dynamic keys

Example if want to filter object based on selected `avaiable_items` i.e `"1"`, the result will be:

```
{
"item": [{"id": "201259","name": "ABC"},{"id": "201303","name"}]
}
```

Comment: Can you try this? 


```
const getItemById = (id: string) => {
  return data.items.find((item) => item.id === id);
};

const filteredItems = [];

const key = "1";

data.avaiable_items[key].map((id) => getItemById(id)).forEach((item) => filteredItems.push(item));

return { item: filteredItems };
```

Comment: so if 2 is it `{
"item": [{"id": "201303","name": "DEF"}]
}` and 3  `{
"item": [{"id": "201259","name": "ABC"}]
}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
const keys = new Set(data.avaiable_items['1']);
data.items.filter(({id}) => keys.has(Number(id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I have misunderstood, however this should work:

```js
const data = 
{
  "avaiable_items": {"1": [201259, 201303],"2": [201303], "3": [201259]},
  "items": [{"id": "201259","name": "ABC"},{"id": "201303","name": "DEF"}]
}

let filterOn = "1";
const newData = data.items.filter(key => {
  return data['avaiable_items'][filterOn].includes(parseInt(key.id));
});

console.log(newData);
```

The above will just filter (and return) those in `items[]` which contain an `id` found in `avaiable_items[x]`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vanilla answer would do:

```js
const myFilter = (
  target = '', 
  {available_items = [], items = [], stock = available_items [target] ?? []} = {}
) => items .filter (({id}) => stock. includes (Number (id)))

const data = {available_items: {1: [201259, 201303], 2: [201303], 3: [201259]}, items: [{id: "201259", name: "ABC"}, {id: "201303", name: "DEF"}]}

console .log ('1:', myFilter (1, data))
console .log ('2:', myFilter (2, data))
console .log ('3:', myFilter (3, data))
console .log ('4:', myFilter (4, data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Although we could certainly use Ramda's `filter` and `includes` in place of the native ones, and could extend this to some point-free version if we tried hard enough, I don't see that it would improve the code at all in this case.